# Fetchnig loss per iteration in MLPRegressor

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, regression

How to Fetching all Loss per iteration in MLPRegressor, to plotting convergence, i need to fetching all loss per iteration (Loss History)

plotting convergence like bellow
[image: Plotting Loss per Iteration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the default `adam` solver method, it is stored in the variable `loss_curve_`.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(model.loss_curve_).plot() #or just plt.plot...
```

`model` refers to your `MLPRegressor` instance name..

Comment: That means an object got plotted. Now it needs rendering? `plt.show()` might do the trick..

Comment: i got loss just in iteration 28, i defined number of iteration = 5000